# how to add a pushkey when manually entering data via the firebase console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to create data in a new firebase database and I need to include pushkeys. I know it can import data via a JSON file I do not know how to create a pushkey in a JSON file.

I have tried using the firebase console data entry tool but could not figure out how to do it. Googling the problem did not supply and results.

If anyone can help I would prefer to use the firebase data entry tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write any key just be sure that your key is not duplicated and upload your JSON file, there is no problem doing that

Comment: Technically, a push id is derived from the current date and time, so that they sort chronologically.  You can use any string instead, but it will not behave like a real push id in this case.

Comment: he can by using `DatabaseReference ref = mRef.push();
String key = ref.getKey();`

Comment: Where would you type that into the firebase console?  The question is about data entry there, not writing code.

Comment: sorry there was an other question like what your's i got confused, you can right a simple js file that uses the `push()` method and read the key after that